# Pandas start generating Run-time warning error and require restart

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

tempdata = np.random.random(10)
myseries = pd.Series(tempdata)

newseries =  myseries[2:6]
```

Now if I put **newseries** in **pd.Series** and want to re-index(I know indexing is immutable) it with some alphabets 
I encounter following error.

**According to pandas documentation Series can accept data as a Python dict or an ndarray or a scaler value**

```
newseries = pd.Series(newseries, index = ['a','b','c','d'])

C:\Users\user110244\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py:2191: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  has_large_values = (abs_vals > 1e6).any()
C:\Users\user110244\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py:2192: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less
  has_small_values = ((abs_vals < 10**(-self.digits)) &
C:\Users\user110244\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\formats\format.py:2193: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater
  (abs_vals > 0)).any()
```

This error display continuously till I restart my Python.Even if try to execute some other simple command say

```
a = 2
```

the same error occured again.
I just want to know why this is happening ? If I am wrong at some place then it will be better to display the error rather than continuously reoccurance of same thing. Is this a bug ? Please explain

My system details are:-
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.1.1 (64-bit)| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] Win10 Pro

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the same error. Since the indices 'a', 'b' etc are not in the orginal series, they get a NaN value, and the numbers are lost.

I think you want to discard the old index and start with a new one, So you can do

```
newseries = pd.Series(newseries.values, index = ['a','b','c','d'])
```

Comment: ok so the catch is  you are feeding the newseries.values i.e. ndarray.  But here I want to know why the error is continuously chasing the output once it is initiated. Please try above code and tell me are you getting the same error and help me find why this is happening

Comment: I don't get that error with your code. Your code produces a series a:NaN, b:NaN, c:NaN, d:NaN